# occurences of words in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array my

```
array=["hello","goodbye","hello","hello","goodbye"];
```

and i want this array to count the occurrences of each word and print a table with each word and how many times is seen to the array in JavaScript. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array=["hello","goodbye","hello","hello","goodbye"];
var count = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    count[array[i]] = (count[array[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(count);
```

HTML Output:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var word in count) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + word + '</td><td>' + count[word] + '</td>';
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: +1 but why stringify ?

Comment: Yeah, no reason for that. Just removed it.

Comment: and when i want to print the element in each line of the table how i am going t do it?

Comment: @user3238361 You mean you want to output it in a HTML table, right?

Comment: I am creating table with JavaScript.

Comment: is ok if I use HTML to create the table. but I want to print in each line the words and theit occurences.

Comment: @user3238361 Read my edit.

Comment: and another thing. how can i sort the words with ASCII ordering?

Comment: I want to say thank you! It was very useful! :)

Comment: why you enter || 0 )+1... can you explain me what is that?

Comment: This means that if `count[array[i]]` is `undefined`, then It'll be set to 0, and then it will add 1.